# how to change nodename with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this XML and need to change the format

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<request type="POST">
    <paths count="0"/>
    <values count="71">
        <timestamp>2017-01-18T21:38:22+01:00</timestamp>
                <CampaignId>7f27a</CampaignId>
                <CampaignCode>CMP-01084-C5R2J5</CampaignCode>
        <Apple>
            <a>Appel</a>
            <b>Appel</b>

        </Apple>
        <Peach>
            <a>Appel</a>
            <b>Appel</b>

        </Peach>
    </values>
    <files count="0"/>
    <header>
        <ipaddress>127.0.0.1</ipaddress>
        <reqheader>thankyou</reqheader>
        <referer/>
        <![CDATA[Host=  localhost:8083]]>
        <cookies/>
    </header>
</request>
```

**I only need the values in `<values>` and change the `<apple>`, `<peach>` etc in `<value>`. Something like this..

```
<soapenv:Envelope>
        <soapenv:Header/>
          <soapenv:Body>
                <timestamp>2017-01-18T21:38:22+01:00</timestamp>
                <CampaignId>7f27a</CampaignId>
                <CampaignCode>CMP-01084-C5R2J5</CampaignCode>
                <value>
                    <a>Appel</a>
                    <b>Appel</b>
                </value>
                <value>
                    <a>Appel</a>
                    <b>Appel</b>
                </value>    
        </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

It has taken more than 8 hours without any progress.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started. See the comments in the XSLT for more details.

Note that in your output you use the namespace prefix `soapenv`. For your output to be [namespace well-formed](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#Conformance), you need to bind that prefix to a namespace uri.

In my XSLT, I've used the uri `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/`; change that if you need to.

**XML Input** (fixed to be [well-formed](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-well-formed) (missing `</values>`))

```
<request type="POST">
    <paths count="0"/>
    <values count="71">
        <timestamp>2017-01-18T21:38:22+01:00</timestamp>
        <CampaignId>7f27a</CampaignId>
        <CampaignCode>CMP-01084-C5R2J5</CampaignCode>
        <Apple>
            <a>Appel</a>
            <b>Appel</b>
        </Apple>
        <Peach>
            <a>Appel</a>
            <b>Appel</b>
        </Peach>
    </values>
    <files count="0"/>
    <header>
        <ipaddress>127.0.0.1</ipaddress>
        <reqheader>thankyou</reqheader>
        <referer/>
        <![CDATA[Host=  localhost:8083]]>
        <cookies/>
    </header>
</request>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!--Copy any attribute or node() (element, text, comment, processing
  instruction) without change. Override this with a more specific template
  when needed.-->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--Match the root element "request" and narrow the elements being processed
  to children of the "values" element.-->
  <xsl:template match="/request">
    <soapenv:Envelope>
      <soapenv:Header/>
      <soapenv:Body>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="values/*"/>
      </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--Change the name of elements to "value" except for timestamp, 
  CampaignId, and CampaignCode. Those should be left alone.-->
  <xsl:template match="Apple|Peach">
    <value>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </value>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <timestamp>2017-01-18T21:38:22+01:00</timestamp>
      <CampaignId>7f27a</CampaignId>
      <CampaignCode>CMP-01084-C5R2J5</CampaignCode>
      <value>
         <a>Appel</a>
         <b>Appel</b>
      </value>
      <value>
         <a>Appel</a>
         <b>Appel</b>
      </value>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

---

Edit based on the following comment:

> Unfortunately this does change the name of every node that has childs
>   to 'value', and not only the targeting ones.

It wasn't 100% clear to me that you only wanted to target `Apple` and `Peach` (because of the "etc").